# Algol: correct syntax leads to problems in compilation?

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, algol68

Here is a relatively simple code for *"Evaluation of pi using the Mid-ordinate Rule on a quadrant of circle with radius 2 units."*

`main.alg`

```
BEGIN
REAL x, y, sumy, pi;
INT n := lowerlimit, p := 1, lowerlimit := 10, upperlimit := 100, interval := 10;

FOR n BY interval TO upperlimit DO
    sumy := 0.0;

    FOR p BY 2 TO n+n-1 DO 
        x := p/n;
        y := sqrt(4.0 - x**2);
        sumy := sumy + y;
    OD
    pi := sumy * (2.0 / n);
    print((n,pi))
OD
END
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
a68g: syntax error: 1: possibly a missing or erroneous separator nearby.                                                                             
sh-4.3$ a68g main.alg                                                                                                                                
13                sumy := sumy + y;                                                                                                                  
                              1                                                                                                                  
a68g: warning: 1: skipped superfluous semi-symbol.                                                                                                   
15            pi := sumy * (2.0 / n);                                                                                                                
          1                                                                                                                                      
a68g: syntax error: 1: possibly a missing or erroneous separator nearby.
```

Try it [live here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_algol_online.php).

What am I doing wrong? How to correct it?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***The short answer:***
The following code has your specific problem fixed...

The thing to remember is that a ";" is a "statement separator"... so all "compound statement" should have each statement separated by a ";".. eg consider:

```
statement; statement; statement # is a valid program #
statement; statement statement; # is not valid #

(statement; statement; statement) # is a valid program #
(statement; statement; statement;) # is not valid #
(statement; statement; statement); # is not valid #
```

The moral is... separate all statements with a ";" and dont put a ";" after the last statement.  (eg before an END, FI, DO, ")"  or ESAC)

```
BEGIN
REAL x, y, sumy, pi;
INT n := lowerlimit, p := 1, lowerlimit := 10, upperlimit := 100, interval := 10;

FOR n BY interval TO upperlimit DO
    sumy := 0.0;

    FOR p BY 2 TO n+n-1 DO 
        x := p/n;
        y := sqrt(4.0 - x**2);
        sumy := sumy + y
    OD;
    pi := sumy * (2.0 / n);
    print((n,pi))
OD
END
```

It is interesting to note that you can often use a "," instead of a ";", this tells the compiler you dont care what order the statements are run.  It is called a GOMMA.  (A contraction of **go on** and **comma**)

e.g. The GOMMA should be used sparingly as the compiler is not required to warn you about side effects... for example (in theory)

```
#!/usr/bin/a68g --script #
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #

INT x:=0;
(x+:=1, x+:=2); # allow the compiler the choice of threading #
PAR(x+:=10, x+:=20); # force statements into different threads #
printf(($"Answer="gl$,x))
```

What is the Answer? ... it could be 33, but it might also be 21 or 12 etc. depending on your compiler.

In this case the +:= operation is so small and fast that the answer will probably be 33.

***The long answer:***
The location of the statement separators in languages cause caused grief through the years.  For example consider the following FORTRAN code with a missing comma:

```
DO 999 I=1 1000
  PRINT *,I
999 CONTINUE
```

This bug was found and corrected before the launch of [Project Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Mercury).  Urban myth has it that the  [Mariner Program](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=bFXeTMPfDYUC&lpg=PP1&dq=Ceruzzi%20%22Beyond%20the%20Limits%22&pg=PR3#v=onepage&q=fortran&f=false) had a similar bug causing it to crash.

Note that it is often useful to have "Fake" statements, this is used to fulfill syntax/semantic requirements.  Python as various examples, eg: "None", "NoneType" and "pass".  Algol68 has "VOID", "SKIP" and "~"

To demonstrate the usage of SKIP (or "~").

```
BEGIN
REAL x, y, sumy, pi;
INT n := lowerlimit, p := 1, lowerlimit := 10, upperlimit := 100, interval := 10;

FOR n BY interval TO upperlimit DO
    sumy := 0.0;

    FOR p BY 2 TO n+n-1 DO 
        x := p/n;
        y := sqrt(4.0 - x**2);
        sumy := sumy + y; SKIP # insert a "fake statement after the ";" #
    OD; # the ";" is still needed #
    pi := sumy * (2.0 / n);
    print((n,pi))
OD
END
```

SKIP is often used to permit code to be cleanly commented out:

```
statement1;
statement2;
SKIP COMMENT
statement3;
statement4 # eg. no ";" on the last statement #
END COMMENT
```

**Without** the SKIP the program would not compile.

In the case of Algol68, there is a weird case [Yoneda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobuo_Yoneda)'s ambiguity.  This ambiguity has haunted numerous programming languages ever since, including Ada and python, and maybe even C...

To find out more go to your university library and read: ["A History of ALGOL 68"](http://web.archive.org/web/20120620044944/http://cs305.com/book/programming_languages/Conf-01/HOPLII/p27-lindsey.pdf) - by C. H. Lindsey - [Includes a candid reflection of the language design process "Revision by mail", language feature struggles "The Bend" and included/excluded ambiguities (eg Yoneda's ambiguity and incestuous unions)]

In python they tries to side step the "Separator" by making it optional and hiding it with indentation... but the comma ambiguity remained.. eg. spot the syntax/semantic error, and run time error in the following...

```
print [i for i in ()]
print [i for i in (1)]
print [i for i in (1,2)]
print [i for i in (1,2,3)]
ab="ab etc etc etc"
print "first 2 only: %c,%c"%ab[0:2]
```

C also suffers a little from "where do I put a semicolon and comma"... the logic is that the ";" need never follow a "}", eg always ";}" but never "};"...  It turns out that **sometimes** you **do** need ";};"

Then C completely throws a spanner in the works for commas with never ",)" but sometimes "),".

1968's Algol68 does produce an error message for this class of ambiguities.  The moral to the story *might* be: if your compiler does not pick up this kind of ambiguity at compile time, then **(just maybe)** you should pick another language.

BTW: You can find some sample Algol68 Programs [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/User:NevilleDNZ#ALGOL_68_Contributions_up_to_2010)...  And next is your code with the sharp edges removed.

```
INT lower limit = 10, upper limit = 100, interval = 10;

PROC circle = (REAL x)REAL: sqrt(4 - x**2);

FOR n FROM lower limit BY interval TO upper limit DO
    REAL sum y := 0;

    FOR p FROM 1 BY 2 TO 2*n DO
        REAL x = p/n;
        REAL y = circle(x);
        sum y +:= y
    OD;
    REAL pi := sum y * 2 / n;
    printf(($g(0)": "g(-real width,real width-2)l$,n,pi))
OD
```

Compare the code changes to see if you can figure out the effect and what hints they provide... :-)

***Or...*** here is how a standard numerical quadrature program might be coded for sharing.  Note the use of passing functions as arguments, in particular there is a concept called Currying here `circle(2,)` ... where the comma is significant!

```
INT lower limit = 10, upper limit = 100, interval = 10;

PROC circle = (REAL radius, x)REAL: sqrt(radius**2 - x**2);

PROC mid point integrate = (PROC(REAL)REAL f, REAL lwb, upb, INT num steps)REAL: (
  REAL dx := (upb - lwb ) / num steps;
  REAL x := lwb + dx/2;
  REAL sum y := 0;

  FOR p TO num steps DO
      REAL y = f(x);
      sum y +:= y;
      x +:= dx
  OD;
  sum y * dx
);

FOR num steps FROM lower limit BY interval TO upper limit DO
  REAL pi := mid point integrate(circle(2,),0,2,num steps);
  printf(($g(0)": "g(-real width,real width-2)l$,num steps,pi))
OD
```

Comment: Thank you for the great, extensive and very informative answer!

Comment: BTW: Algol68 has some other things that are a bit quirky, but fun. For example, in Algol68 programmers are not requiredtomumble when they declare variables.  They can instead declare and use variable `sumy` and `upperlimit` as follows:  `REAL x, y, sum y, pi;
INT n := lower limit, p := 1, lower limit := 10, upper limit := 100, interval := 10;`

Comment: The construction ```(x += 1, x += 2)``` is a collateral-clause, and the comma is just a comma-symbol.

Comment: I believe you have 'gomma' wrong. In procedure calls, actual parameters are separated by comms-symbols foo(a, b) and are elaborated collaterally, i.e., in undefined order. The original Report allowed gommas in place of commas: foo(a; b) to force serial elaboration of actual-parameters at the choice of the caller. i.e., a gomma had the reverse effect of what you're saying: it forced the order of elaboration. Gommas were removed in the Revised Report

Comment: re: gomma... indeed you are right ... ";"  is a "gomma", and "," is a "comma".  i.e. I just checked the Final Report (r0) in section 3.1.1.f it states a "go on symbol" is either ";" or ".," ... I presume that the ".," gomma is for computers whose character set does not include a semicolon... So all these years I could have called a "semicolon" a gomma! ;-)

Comment: The 1968 Final Report (r0) also lists an "up to" symbol as either ":" or ".." - So you can also dimension an array as either [1:100]REAL or [1..100]REAL!  - The ".." as an up-to symbol is kind of poetic.